# How to retrieve field value from other modules in odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I want to retrieve a field called "product_qty" from manufacturing module.It is defined in mrp_bom class.All examples of related fields shows that both the classes exist in same file.Is it possible to get the value of "product_qty" which is in mrp module and retrieve it in my class defined in my custom module?

```
class product_template(models.Model):
    _inherit = "product.template"
    product_quantity = fields.Many2one('mrp.bom')
    quantity = fields.Char(related='product_quantity.product_qty')
```

Comment: Try with a `Float` field instead of `Char` field

Comment: Now I am not getting any errors but quantity field is not created in the database

Comment: Are you sure that you need to store it? Normally this is not necessary because the field is recovered each time from the related field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The fields will be created in database only if it's store=True (in
>   case of related field or functional field).
>    Related values will not be available until you save that record (on create time).

You should try following,

```
class product_template(models.Model):
    _inherit = "product.template"
    product_quantity = fields.Many2one('mrp.bom')
    quantity = fields.Float(string="Qty", related='product_quantity.product_qty', store=True, readonly=True)
```